# YouCompleteMe doesn't complete functions from headers

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me

After downloading YouCompleteMe from ubuntu repositories and installing it I have used [this script](https://github.com/ycm-core/ycmd/blob/master/examples/.ycm_extra_conf.py) as extra config. I suppose this config may help me with in-headers functions auto-completion.

:YcmDebugInfo shows

```
    Printing YouCompleteMe debug information...
    -- Resolve completions: Up front
    -- Client logfile: /tmp/ycm_mdq0n_kl.log
    -- Server Python interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    -- Server Python version: 3.9.5
    -- Server has Clang support compiled in: True
    -- Clang version: Ubuntu clang version 11.0.1-2ubuntu4
    -- Extra configuration file found and loaded
    -- Extra configuration path: /project/.ycm_extra_conf.py
    -- C-family completer debug information:
    --   Clangd running
    --   Clangd process ID: 3823704
    --   Clangd executable: ['/usr/bin/clangd', '-header-insertion-decorators=0', '-limit-results=500']
    --   Clangd logfiles:
    --     /tmp/clangd_stderrg57o740a.log
    --   Clangd Server State: Initialized
    --   Clangd Project Directory: /project/sources/examples/hello
    --   Clangd Settings: {}
    --   Clangd Compilation Command: ['clang-tool', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror', '-fexceptions', '-std=c89', '-xc', '-I./sources/drivers', '-I
    ./os/core', '/project/examples/hello/hello.c']
    -- Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:37731
    -- Server process ID: 3823664
    -- Server logfiles:
    --   /tmp/ycmd_37731_stdout_wl6kpb5o.log
    --   /tmp/ycmd_37731_stderr_qxt4yeoa.log
```

/tmp/ycmd_37731_stderr_qxt4yeoa.log contains some errors:

```
2021-07-27 15:10:48,825 - INFO - Completion config: 50, detailing -1 candiates
2021-07-27 15:10:48,825 - INFO - Completion config: 50, detailing -1 candiates
2021-07-27 15:10:48,825 - INFO - Completion config: 50, detailing -1 candiates
2021-07-27 15:10:48,825 - INFO - Completion config: 50, detailing -1 candiates
2021-07-27 15:10:48,853 - INFO - Received ready request
2021-07-27 15:10:48,855 - INFO - Received signature help available request
2021-07-27 15:10:48,856 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:10:48,858 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:10:48,858 - INFO - Adding buffer identifiers for file: /project/sources/examples/hello/hello.c
2021-07-27 15:10:48,894 - INFO - Using Clangd from /usr/bin/clangd
2021-07-27 15:10:48,894 - INFO - Computed Clangd command: ['/usr/bin/clangd', '-header-insertion-decorators=0', '-limit-results=500']
2021-07-27 15:10:48,894 - INFO - Completion config: 50, detailing -1 candiates
2021-07-27 15:10:48,894 - INFO - Returning cached Clangd command: ['/usr/bin/clangd', '-header-insertion-decorators=0', '-limit-results=500']
2021-07-27 15:10:48,895 - INFO - Starting Clangd: ['/usr/bin/clangd', '-header-insertion-decorators=0', '-limit-results=500']
2021-07-27 15:10:48,899 - INFO - Clangd started with PID 3823704
2021-07-27 15:10:48,928 - INFO - None: Language server does not require resolve request
2021-07-27 15:10:48,929 - INFO - None: Language server requires sync type of Incremental
2021-07-27 15:10:48,929 - INFO - cfamily: Using characters for signature triggers: (,,
2021-07-27 15:10:48,957 - INFO - Received filetype completion available request
2021-07-27 15:10:51,764 - INFO - Received debug info request
2021-07-27 15:10:54,096 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:10:54,101 - INFO - Received signature help available request
2021-07-27 15:10:54,214 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:10:54,219 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:10:54,226 - INFO - Received signature help request
2021-07-27 15:10:55,229 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:10:55,230 - INFO - Adding buffer identifiers for file: /project/sources/examples/hello/hello.c
2021-07-27 15:10:55,234 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:10:55,235 - INFO - Adding ONE buffer identifier for file: /project/sources/examples/hello/hello.c
2021-07-27 15:10:56,590 - INFO - Received debug info request
2021-07-27 15:11:09,495 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:11:09,500 - INFO - Received signature help request
2021-07-27 15:11:10,027 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:11:10,030 - INFO - Received signature help request
2021-07-27 15:11:10,813 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:11:10,814 - INFO - Adding buffer identifiers for file: /project/sources/examples/hello/hello.c
2021-07-27 15:11:10,818 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:11:10,818 - INFO - Adding ONE buffer identifier for file: /project/sources/examples/hello/hello.c
2021-07-27 15:11:11,176 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:11:13,795 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:11:15,105 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:11:15,110 - INFO - Received signature help request
2021-07-27 15:11:15,534 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:11:15,536 - INFO - Received signature help request
2021-07-27 15:11:15,745 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:11:15,751 - INFO - Received signature help request
2021-07-27 15:11:15,937 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:11:15,941 - INFO - Received signature help request
2021-07-27 15:11:16,670 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:11:16,671 - INFO - Received signature help request
2021-07-27 15:11:17,385 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:11:17,386 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:11:17,386 - INFO - Adding buffer identifiers for file: /project/sources/examples/hello/hello.c
2021-07-27 15:11:20,134 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:11:20,135 - INFO - Received signature help request
2021-07-27 15:11:20,243 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:11:20,249 - INFO - Received signature help request
2021-07-27 15:11:20,547 - INFO - Received completion request
2021-07-27 15:11:20,552 - INFO - Received signature help request
2021-07-27 15:11:21,246 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:11:21,247 - INFO - Adding buffer identifiers for file: /project/sources/examples/hello/hello.c
2021-07-27 15:11:21,250 - INFO - Received event notification
2021-07-27 15:11:21,251 - INFO - Adding ONE buffer identifier for file: /project/sources/examples/hello/hello.c
2021-07-27 15:11:26,612 - INFO - Received defined subcommands request
2021-07-27 15:11:26,612 - INFO - Found executeCommandProvider support for command ExecuteCommand in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,613 - INFO - Found codeActionProvider support for command FixIt in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,613 - INFO - Found definitionProvider support for command GoToDefinition in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,613 - INFO - Found declarationProvider support for command GoToDeclaration in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,613 - INFO - Found ('definitionProvider', 'declarationProvider') support for command GoTo in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,613 - INFO - No support for GoToType command in server for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,613 - INFO - Found implementationProvider support for command GoToImplementation in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,613 - INFO - Found referencesProvider support for command GoToReferences in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,614 - INFO - Found renameProvider support for command RefactorRename in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,614 - INFO - Found documentFormattingProvider support for command Format in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,614 - INFO - Found workspaceSymbolProvider support for command GoToSymbol in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,614 - INFO - Always supporting StopServer for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,614 - INFO - Always supporting RestartServer for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,614 - INFO - Always supporting GetDoc for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,614 - INFO - Always supporting GetType for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,614 - INFO - Always supporting GetTypeImprecise for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,614 - INFO - Always supporting GoToImprecise for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,614 - INFO - Always supporting GoToInclude for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,615 - INFO - Always supporting GetDocImprecise for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,622 - INFO - Received command request
2021-07-27 15:11:26,623 - INFO - Found executeCommandProvider support for command ExecuteCommand in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,623 - INFO - Found codeActionProvider support for command FixIt in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,623 - INFO - Found definitionProvider support for command GoToDefinition in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,623 - INFO - Found declarationProvider support for command GoToDeclaration in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,623 - INFO - Found ('definitionProvider', 'declarationProvider') support for command GoTo in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,623 - INFO - No support for GoToType command in server for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,623 - INFO - Found implementationProvider support for command GoToImplementation in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,624 - INFO - Found referencesProvider support for command GoToReferences in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,624 - INFO - Found renameProvider support for command RefactorRename in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,624 - INFO - Found documentFormattingProvider support for command Format in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,624 - INFO - Found workspaceSymbolProvider support for command GoToSymbol in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,624 - INFO - Always supporting StopServer for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,624 - INFO - Always supporting RestartServer for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,624 - INFO - Always supporting GetDoc for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,624 - INFO - Always supporting GetType for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,624 - INFO - Always supporting GetTypeImprecise for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,624 - INFO - Always supporting GoToImprecise for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,625 - INFO - Always supporting GoToInclude for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:26,625 - INFO - Always supporting GetDocImprecise for cfamily
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/completers/cpp/clangd_completer.py", line 227, in GetDoc
    self.GetHoverResponse( request_data )[ 'value' ] )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/completers/language_server/language_server_completer.py", line 2343, in GetHoverResponse
    raise NoHoverInfoException( NO_HOVER_INFORMATION )
ycmd.completers.language_server.language_server_completer.NoHoverInfoException: No hover information.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 868, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1748, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/watchdog_plugin.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return callback( *args, **kwargs )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/hmac_plugin.py", line 62, in wrapper
    body = callback( *args, **kwargs )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/handlers.py", line 94, in RunCompleterCommand
    return _JsonResponse( completer.OnUserCommand(
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/completers/completer.py", line 472, in OnUserCommand
    return command( self, request_data, arguments[ 1: ] )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/completers/language_server/language_server_completer.py", line 1648, in <lambda>
    lambda self, request_data, args: self.GetDoc( request_data )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/completers/cpp/clangd_completer.py", line 229, in GetDoc
    raise RuntimeError( 'No documentation available.' )
RuntimeError: No documentation available.
2021-07-27 15:11:39,026 - INFO - Received command request
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Found executeCommandProvider support for command ExecuteCommand in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Found codeActionProvider support for command FixIt in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Found definitionProvider support for command GoToDefinition in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Found declarationProvider support for command GoToDeclaration in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Found ('definitionProvider', 'declarationProvider') support for command GoTo in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - No support for GoToType command in server for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Found implementationProvider support for command GoToImplementation in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Found referencesProvider support for command GoToReferences in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Found renameProvider support for command RefactorRename in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Found documentFormattingProvider support for command Format in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Found workspaceSymbolProvider support for command GoToSymbol in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Always supporting StopServer for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Always supporting RestartServer for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Always supporting GetDoc for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,027 - INFO - Always supporting GetType for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,028 - INFO - Always supporting GetTypeImprecise for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,028 - INFO - Always supporting GoToImprecise for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,028 - INFO - Always supporting GoToInclude for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:11:39,028 - INFO - Always supporting GetDocImprecise for cfamily
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 868, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1748, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/watchdog_plugin.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return callback( *args, **kwargs )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/hmac_plugin.py", line 62, in wrapper
    body = callback( *args, **kwargs )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/handlers.py", line 94, in RunCompleterCommand
    return _JsonResponse( completer.OnUserCommand(
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/completers/completer.py", line 463, in OnUserCommand
    raise ValueError( self.UserCommandsHelpMessage() )
ValueError: Supported commands are:
ExecuteCommand
FixIt
Format
GetDoc
GetDocImprecise
GetType
GetTypeImprecise
GoTo
GoToDeclaration
GoToDefinition
GoToImplementation
GoToImprecise
GoToInclude
GoToReferences
GoToSymbol
RefactorRename
RestartServer
See the docs for information on what they do.
2021-07-27 15:11:52,516 - INFO - Received debug info request
2021-07-27 15:16:38,416 - INFO - Received command request
2021-07-27 15:16:38,417 - INFO - Found executeCommandProvider support for command ExecuteCommand in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,417 - INFO - Found codeActionProvider support for command FixIt in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,417 - INFO - Found definitionProvider support for command GoToDefinition in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,417 - INFO - Found declarationProvider support for command GoToDeclaration in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,417 - INFO - Found ('definitionProvider', 'declarationProvider') support for command GoTo in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,417 - INFO - No support for GoToType command in server for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,417 - INFO - Found implementationProvider support for command GoToImplementation in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,418 - INFO - Found referencesProvider support for command GoToReferences in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,418 - INFO - Found renameProvider support for command RefactorRename in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,418 - INFO - Found documentFormattingProvider support for command Format in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,418 - INFO - Found workspaceSymbolProvider support for command GoToSymbol in cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,418 - INFO - Always supporting StopServer for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,418 - INFO - Always supporting RestartServer for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,418 - INFO - Always supporting GetDoc for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,418 - INFO - Always supporting GetType for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,418 - INFO - Always supporting GetTypeImprecise for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,418 - INFO - Always supporting GoToImprecise for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,419 - INFO - Always supporting GoToInclude for cfamily
2021-07-27 15:16:38,419 - INFO - Always supporting GetDocImprecise for cfamily
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/completers/cpp/clangd_completer.py", line 227, in GetDoc
    self.GetHoverResponse( request_data )[ 'value' ] )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/completers/language_server/language_server_completer.py", line 2343, in GetHoverResponse
    raise NoHoverInfoException( NO_HOVER_INFORMATION )
ycmd.completers.language_server.language_server_completer.NoHoverInfoException: No hover information.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 868, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1748, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/watchdog_plugin.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return callback( *args, **kwargs )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/hmac_plugin.py", line 62, in wrapper
    body = callback( *args, **kwargs )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/handlers.py", line 94, in RunCompleterCommand
    return _JsonResponse( completer.OnUserCommand(
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/completers/completer.py", line 472, in OnUserCommand
    return command( self, request_data, arguments[ 1: ] )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/completers/language_server/language_server_completer.py", line 1648, in <lambda>
    lambda self, request_data, args: self.GetDoc( request_data )
  File "/usr/lib/ycmd/ycmd/completers/cpp/clangd_completer.py", line 229, in GetDoc
    raise RuntimeError( 'No documentation available.' )
RuntimeError: No documentation available.
```

Currently the problem is that plugin doesn't complete functions from headers, only from current file.
I spent several hours but still have no idea how to fix this, need help.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
```

Comment: Probably you're best asking the YCM devs. None of the error text means much to me, though it might to folks who use the plugin. (PS Guessing that the config helps with a particular thing is probably a poor way to go—you may want to read the docs for the plugin and find out how to configure it to use headers. Vim can natively complete from included files with `<C-x><C-I>` see `:help compl-keyword` if configured to detect and find includes correctly.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble very nice, that is enough, you can post this as an answer if you wish. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a YCM answer, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> will complete from included files, assuming `path`/`include`/etc. are configured correctly. See `:help compl-keyword` for more.